# How to know if a file is completely written to disk in Windows. (With disk Write Cache policy disabled)

Tags: sql, windows, disk, ntfs

I am trying to take a backup log of a SQL database to a disk and then take a snapshot of the disk.  To ensure that the write happens by surpassing the disk write cache, I have disabled the disk write cache by enabling `Quick Removal` policy so that the file would be directly written to the disk. The transaction file shows on the location but it is not showing up on the disk's snapshot, which was because the file had not yet been written completely to the disk yet. The OS thinks the file is accessible as I tried opening the file via powershell after the backup completed (and before the snapshot), and it was allowed (otherwise it should have shown that the file is being used by another process). Is there a method to find whether a file is completely written to the disk ?

Comment: you can call [`FlushFileBuffers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-flushfilebuffers) after write complete for force flush all data to disk.

Comment: @RbMm ,  I am executing `BACKUP LOG TO DISK` for writing the logs from the database to the disk. Will using `FlushFileBuffers` after that work ?

Comment: i not understand your question. `FlushFileBuffers` force flush file cache to disk. how this related to backup or to what file you write ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was thinking about whether `FlushFileBuffers` is called internally in the backup ( [I was looking into a link I found](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/log-backup-failing-due-to-flushfilebuffers) ). I will try out using `FlushFileBuffers`.